# "Substitude" parent class in python or make Sympy's objects display in latex by default

Tags: python, sympy

The goal is to display sympy's objects (which all inherit from Printable class) not in sstr(), but in latex() by default

*Example:*

```
from sympy import symbols, sqrt
x, y = symbols('x y')
print(f'its {sqrt(x)} and {sqrt(y)}')
#output:
'its \\sqrt(x) and \\sqrt(y)'
```

That works if I change the sympy's source code editing Printable Class' `__str__` method.
Are there any ways to make imported sympy's classes inherit from my class, not the source one without editing the actual source?

I tried this:

```
from sympy.core._print_helpers import Printable
class PrintableWrapper(Printable):
    def __str__(self):
        from sympy.printing.latex import latex
        return latex(self, mode='plain')
    __repr__ = __str__
Printable = PrintableWrapper

from sympy import Symbol, sqrt
Printable = PrintableWrapper
A = Symbol("A")
print(f'{sqrt(A)}')
#output:
'sqrt(A)'
```

But as you can see, it doesn't work

The reason I am asking is because I use Ipython's display(Math(f'...')) funtions to display stuff and I have to wrap any single sympy object into latex() like this:

```
display(Math(f'its {latex(sqrt(x))} and {latex(sqrt(y))}''))
```

So any solutions to make `f'its {sqrt(x)} and {sqrt(y)}'` work are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the function in the internal class, extending the class keeps the internal class unchanged.

```
from sympy.core._print_helpers import Printable
from sympy.printing.latex import latex
class PrintableWrapper:
    def __str__(self):
        return latex(self, mode='plain')
    __repr__ = __str__
Printable.__repr__ = PrintableWrapper.__str__
Printable.__str__  = PrintableWrapper.__str__

from sympy import Symbol, sqrt
Printable = PrintableWrapper
A = Symbol("A")
print(f'{sqrt(A)}')
```